# Factoring $(1+i)z^2 - 3z +2 - i$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

I'm not sure how to factor $(1+i)z^2 - 3z +2 - i$. I was thinking of writing this as: $$c(z - \alpha)(z -\beta)$$ and solving for $\alpha,\beta$ however that yields some very nasty results. Could someone give me a starting step?

Comment: A friendly advice: [title should NOT be the first sentence of your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/356647). In particular, see the last bullet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $$(1+i)z^2 - 3z +2 - i=(z^2-3z+2)+(z^2-1)i=\color{red}{(z-1)}(z-2)+\color{red}{(z-1)}(z+1)i$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  by inspection $\,z=1\,$ is a root, so one of the factors is $\,z-1\,$.

Comment: Yes I know that, would I normally be expect to do that just by inspection? Also what do I do with the $z-1$, polynomial division? Or do I use it to say $\alpha = 1$?

Comment: @Boots `would I normally be expect to do that just by inspection?` That depends on the context, which you didn't let on much about. If you *expected* a shortcut solution for whatever reason then, yes, checking for $\,z=1\,$ would be one of the first things. `do I use it to say α=1` That's equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

Since $1$ is a root we obtain:
$$(1+i)z^2-3z+2-i=(z-1)((1+i)z-2+i)=(1+i)(z-1)\left(z-\frac{2-i}{1+i}\right)=$$
$$=(1+i)(z-1)\left(z-\frac{2-2i-i-1}{2}\right)=(1+i)(z-1)\left(z-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}i\right)$$